# DIV gets cut off even though width and height are defined

Tags: html, css

I have this on my page:

```
<div id="result" class="thumbholder"><img src="img/thumbs/thumb01.png" alt="thumb" /></div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbholder{
width:100px;
height:100px;
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
border-radius:6px;
float:left;
margin:0;
}
```

The `#result` div is not defined anywhere in CSS (I checked).

The div refuses to show up in 100 x 100 size, instead it cuts off part of the height. It's not that it's just not being displayed all the way, as I can see the lower rounded corners - it actually has a smaller height than defined. Why is this happening?

The image inside is also 100 x 100 in size, but that doesn't matter, the same thing happens whatever I put inside it.

EDIT: defining the height inline also doesn't help.

Comment: Could you give us a jsFiddle to take a look at?

Comment: Works ok for me on google chrome http://jsfiddle.net/uWAMV/

Comment: Works for [http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/8Exf6/](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/8Exf6/) - you must have some other style messing up with your div...

Comment: Same with an image inside... http://jsfiddle.net/vLKdc/

Comment: Yes, I just tried jsFiddle myself and it works. I have a really complex page/css here, so could be a number of things causing the problem I suppose. I'll look at some other options and come back if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Could you just post the full css? I promise we won't steal it.

Comment: Id suggest getting firebug for firefox or chrome, it is great for finding out what is happening with your css!

Comment: Andrew, the full css has 4000 lines :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `!important` to override other code that might be causing the height to not be 100px

> ```
> .thumbholder
> {
>     width:100px !important;
>     height:100px !important;
>     text-align:center;
>     overflow:hidden;
>     border-radius:6px;
>     float:left;
>     margin:0;
> }
> ```

It's not a great solution, but it could help you debug the problem.
Otherwise use Chrome's inspector (or firebug) to find out what is overriding your height definition

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked it out in Firebug to see if the div is inheriting any other styles? Maybe adding '**display:block**' might fix it, sounds like it could be displaying as an inline element if your height property is being ignored... Or possibly there is a max-height: set somewhere, in which case '**max-height:100%**' could work.

Comment: display:block doesn't do anything, nor does max-height.

Comment: After trying out all the posts out there , only this worked `max-height` always gonna remember this

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      <div id="result" class="thumbholder"><img src="img/thumbs/thumb01.png" alt="thumb" /></div>
```